# run php as server without Apache

Tags: php, apache, nginx

Currently I'm working with PHP programming, and I find that I can load a web page just only by using PHP CL, so I don't understand exactly why we have to install additional server like Apache or Nginx.

[image: php.exe server]

Comment: `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` from the directory you are in. The built-in server is meant for development only and doesn't provide much of the features you see in Apache or Nginx. If you are looking for a server that is easier to manage have a look at Caddy.

Comment: Using PHP's built-in server for something public-facing is akin to holding up a power cable with your hand while on a tall ladder instead of digging a hole and putting a pole in it to attach the cable to. You can get away with it for quick testing but it's awfully inconvenient to stay permanent.

Comment: ok good  thnak you very much :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I see it as a question for focusing on a slightly broader but highly related question:  Why should we be extremely careful to only allow specific software onto public-facing infrastructure?  And, even more generally, what sort of software is okay to place onto public-facing infrastructure?  And its corollary, what does good server software look like?

First off, there is no such thing as secure software.  This means you should always hold a very skeptical view of anything that opens a single port on a computer to enable network connections (in either direction).  However, there is a very small set of software that has had enough eyeballs on it to guarantee a certain minimum level of assurance that things will probably not go horribly wrong.  Apache is the most battle-tested server out there and Nginx comes in at a close second as far as modern web servers are concerned.  The built-in PHP HTTP server is not a good choice for a public-facing system let alone testing production software as it lacks the qualities of good network server design and may have undiscovered security vulnerabilities in it.  For those and other reasons, the developers include a warning against using the built-in PHP server.  It was added because users kept asking for it but that doesn't mean it should be used.

It is also a good idea to not trust network servers written by someone who doesn't know what they are doing.  I frequently see ill-conceived network servers written in Node or Go, typically WebSocket-based solutions or just used to work around some issue with another piece of software, that implicitly opens security holes in the infrastructure even if the author didn't intend to do so.  Just because someone can do something doesn't mean that they should and, when it comes to writing network servers, they shouldn't.  Frequently those servers are proxied behind Apache or Nginx, which affords some defense against standard attacks.  However, once an attacker gets past the defenses of Apache or Nginx, it's up to the software to provide its own defenses, which, sadly, is almost always significantly lacking.  As a result, any time I see a proxied service running on a host, I brace myself for the inevitable security disaster that awaits - Ruby, Node, and Go developers being the biggest offenders.  The moment a developer decides to write a network server is the moment they've probably chosen the wrong strategy unless they have a very specific reason to do so AND must be aware of and prepared to defend against a wide range of attack scenarios.  A developer needs to be well-versed in a wide variety of disciplines before taking on the extremely difficult task of writing a network server, scalable or otherwise.  It is my experience that few developers out there are actually capable of that task without introducing major security holes into their own or their users' infrastructure.  While the PHP core developers generally know what they are doing elsewhere, I have personally found several critical bugs in their core networking logic, which shows that they are collectively lacking in that department.  Therefore their built-in web server should be used sparingly, if at all.

Beyond security, Apache and Nginx are designed to handle "load" more so than the built-in PHP server.  What load means is the answer to the question of, "How many requests per second can be serviced?"  The answer is actually extremely complicated.  Depending on code complexity, what is being hosted, what hardware is in use, and what is running at any point in time, a single host can handle anywhere from 20 to 20,000 requests per second and that number can vary greatly from moment to moment.  Apache comes with a tool called Apache Bench (ab) that can be used to benchmark performance of a web server.  However, benchmarks should always be taken with a grain of salt and viewed from the perspective of "Can we get this application to go any faster?" rather than "My application is faster than yours."

As far as developing software in PHP goes, I recommend trying to mirror your production environment as best as possible.  If Apache will be running remotely, then running Apache locally provides the best simulation of the real thing so that there aren't a bunch of last-minute surprises.  PHP code running under the Apache module may have significantly different behavior than PHP code running under the built-in PHP server (e.g. $_SERVER differences)!

If you are like me and don't like setting up Apache and PHP and don't need Apache running all the time, I maintain a set of scripts for setting up portable versions of Apache, PHP, and Maria DB (roughly equivalent to MySQL) for Windows over here:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/portable-apache-maria-db-php-for-windows/

If your software application is actually intended to be run using the built-in PHP server (e.g. a localhost only server), then I highly recommend introducing a buffer layer such as the CubicleSoft WebServer class:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-web-scraper/

By using a PHP userland class like that one, you can gain certain assurances that the built-in PHP server cannot provide while still being a pure PHP solution (i.e. no extra dependencies):  Fewer, if any, buffer overflow opportunities, the server is interpreted through the Zend Engine resulting in fewer rogue code execution opportunities, and has more features than the built-in server including complete customization of the server request/response cycle itself.  PHP itself can start such a server during an OS boot by utilizing a tool similar to Service Manager:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/service-manager/

Of course, that all means that a user has to trust your application's code that opened a port to run on their computer.  For example, what happens if a website starts port scanning localhost ports via the user's web browser?  And, if they do find the port that your software is running on, can that website start deleting files or run code that installs malware?  It's the unusual exploits that will really trip you up.  A "zero open ports" with "disconnected network cable/disabled WiFi" strategy is the only known way to truly secure a device.  Every open port and established connection carries risk.

Good network-enabled software will have been battle-tested and hardened against a wide range of attacks.  Writing such software is a responsibility that takes a lot of time to get right and it will generally show if it is done wrong.  PHP's built-in server feels sloppy and lacks basic configuration options.  I can't recommend its use for any reasonable purpose.

Answer (score 5):

If you refer to the PHP documentation:

> Warning
>
> This web server was designed to aid application development. It may
>   also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations
>   that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a
>   full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

So yes, as it states, this is a good tool for testing purposes. You can quickly start a server and test your scripts in your browser. But that does not mean it provides all of the features you get with a production level server like apache or Nginx :)

You can use the built in server in your local development environment. But you should you use a more secure, feature rich web server in your production environment which requires much more features in terms of security, handling large number of requests etc.